# When to use a Hidden Markov Model vs Markov Model with history?

Tags: time-series, autocorrelation, hidden-markov-model

I'm trying to understand when and why it's useful to use hidden state in a model.  The purpose of my modeling is to be able to simulate sequences with features similar to observed data sets.

As a simple example, suppose I want to model sequence of autocorrelated binary events $ \{ X_t \}$.

I could model them as a HMM:

$$
X_t \sim \mathrm{Bernoulli}(p_t) 
$$
where $p_t \in \{p_1,p_2\} $ has state transition matrix
$$
P = \left( \begin{array}{cc} q & 1-q \\ 1-q & q\end{array} \right)
$$

Alternatively, I could calculate $p_t$ using only past observed values of $X_t$, for example with exponential decay:
$$
p_t = \begin{cases} p_1 & \sum_{i=1}^t \theta^i X_{t-i} > 0 \\ p_2 & \text{otherwise} \end{cases}
$$

How do I choose between these two approaches?  Is one more general than the other?

Comment: The HMM seem to be more general because the Markov model with history as you present seems to be a mixture which is a special case of hidden makov model where each line of the transition matrix is the same.

Comment: But if a markov chain can use any arbitrary funciton of $X_t$'s history, wouldn't it be able to model anyting that a HMM can?  (but perhaps with more parameters needed?)  Maybe a better question is can I transform a HMM into a conditional function on the history of $X_t$?

Comment: The "Markov model with history" introduced here is not a Markov model at all, because it does not make the Markov assumption that future states are independent of past states given the present state. If you want to compute arbitrary functions of the past, you are more interested in something like a recurrent neural network.

Comment: Well any history can be included in a Markov chain by increasing the dimensionality of the state to include past values. I've been experimenting with my data and so far I'm not seeing any advantage to modeling hidden state; it just makes fitting more difficult.

Comment: So is your question about Markov models with lots of states versus Markov models with few states?

Comment: HMM with 1 latent state vs. Markov model with 1 observed state and additional values calculated from lagged values of the observed state.